# Webpack-dev-server serves old file content

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a very simple project:

`appdir
   +- app
      +- main.js
   +- build
      +- bundle.js
      +- index.html
   +- webpack.config.js`

The webpack.config.js:

```
var path=require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./app/main.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
};
```

After I changs the `main.js`, webpack-dev-server seems like it detects the change and performs a rebundle the `bundle.js`, but the browser still recieve the old content of `main.js`.

I start the server by executing `webpack-dev-server webpack.config.js`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Looking into https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/24 , I add the `publicPath` to `webpack.config.js` and the webpack serves the bundle with new content now ^_^

```
var path=require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./app/main.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/build/",
    },
    devServer: {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it turned out to be cause by missing trailing slashes in my src and dist paths in webpack.config.js.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same thing and my directory structure matched yours almost exactly. [The docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output) state that "You must not specify an absolute path [for output.filename]." I didn't see the utility of using the path module given the complexity of the problem.

You may be able to solve the issue this way:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/main.js"
    output: {
        filename: "./build/bundle.js"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to visit https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver and check the configuration there itself. The below piece of code will resolve your problem as it did mine.

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  }
};
```